# Class 'ZipArchive' not found in Laravel phpword

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, phpoffice

I have installed `phpword` package in my laravel project. Now when I try to read a `docx` file using this code

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file);
    foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
        foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
            if(method_exists($element,'getText')) {
                echo $element->getText() . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error

> Class 'ZipArchive' not found
>
> /vendor/phpoffice/common/src/Common/XMLReader.php line no 54

`zip` already installed in my php.
[image]

Comment: Please run command for cache clear and dump-autoload like `php artisan config:cache` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd what a fool I am. You save my day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please run command for cache clear and dump-autoload like `php artisan config:cache` and `composer dump-autoload`